# SQLServer Session State Management Lost On App Pool Recycle

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, session-state

I have an application that has been having issues with losing session, and I'm almost positive  it has to do with the application pool recycling too often.

I wanted to try an out of process solution and have configured SQLServer sessionState, but when I recycle the worker process my session is still being blown away.  Here is my web.config

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424"  mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=(local;User ID=user;Password=password" timeout="180" />
```

I've ran the appropriate sql scripts to setup the database and I can see that a session is created and stored in the database, but if i change the web.config or manually recycle the worker process my session is lost.  What am I doing wrong??

Side note, I'm receiving the exact same behavior with StateServer mode.  I seemingly configure it properly, I can see the State service memory footprint get bigger when I login ....I tried to push a non serialized object into and received an error....but when I recycle the app pool or change the web.config I lose session....

I've also tried to set up the Memcached session provider (which is what I would really like to use) that can be found here: http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/releases/view/10468

and it is also doing the same thing!  I can see the session being created in the database, and I will get an error pertaining to serialization when I try to interact with a non-serialized object....but I lose the session when the app pool is recycled.
After enabling some logging I'm seeing this in the event viewer:
**Event code: 1003 Event message: Application compilation is starting**

Nobody??  I really need to get out of process session state working....help!!

Comment: Maybe you reset on your global.asax something that affect your session data ?

Comment: Is everything you're putting the session serializable?

Comment: How are you establishing that the session is lost? How are you using session state? Do you have the same issues if you use State Server rather than SQL Server?

Comment: @Aristos: No, I have nothing in the global.asax after Application_Start, which contains my URL routes.

Comment: @JohAdams: Yes, I believe I have everything that's being loaded marked as Serializable...but even if I didn't wouldn't it just throw an exception instead of kill my session?  Session seems to be working just fine and I see the record inserted into the ASPState database...I just lose my session when the App Pool is recycled.

Comment: @Damien: When I login to the site, the user info is stored in Session as well as a few other things.  I can navigate through the site and am getting data loaded back from Session.  As soon as I recycle the worker process or edit the web.config I lose session and am being logged out of the system

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings for Machine Key (assuming IIS 7.5). If your web server is set to autogenerate the machine key, it is possible that it is generating a new key when your application recycles and that is causing you to lose session.

See this link here for an easy way generate unique machine keys for your web application. You should be able to generate them at either the web server or web application level.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey.aspx

Also, FWIW, the SQL Server Session State manager is *very* talky with the database. It works, but you will be hitting the database for every request using that Session provider.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I'll check out the link.  Yes, I didn't want to use SQLServer initially, I wanted to use the Memcached Session Provider.  Do you have any experience with that, or can you recommend another solution for out of process session state?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't recommend another provider that I have actually used for anything serious. I have looked into the Couchbase Session state provider, which looks promising. The memcached provider looks cool, but can it support more than 2 GB worth of data on Windows?

Comment: @Cognitronic Did you have any luck with this? Also, what version of IIS are you using?

Comment: Hi @rsbarro, no I had no luck with generating a key.  I did it both from the application level in IIS and by using a key generation tool online...nothing.  I'm using IIS 7.5. Any other ideas??  Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @Cognitronic On your Application Pool, under Advanced Settings, what is the value of Maximum Worker Processes? Also, what is the Managed Pipeline Mode, Classic or Integrated?

Comment: Maximum Worker Processes is set to 1 and the Managed Pipeline Mode is Integrated.  Thanks!!!